# How to break lines using conditions

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

How can I break a line for when the text exceeds the paragraph width?

```
\noindent where

\begin{conditions}

\hspace{1cm}A & This text goes here over the paragraph and I would like to (so somewhere here I would need to do line division) do line division for it so that it comes after the '='-sign \\

\hspace{1cm}\alpha\textsubscript{s} & aaaaaaaaas afasfasf asf as f\\ 

\end{conditions}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm not quite understanding your question.  Could you [edit] this to show us a minimal working example, that doesn't have the line division you want but has a comment where you would like the line division to show?  (Also, the tag "overleaf" is mainly for overleaf specific issues.  Since this is (presumably) more related to LaTeX, it would be better have more specific tags.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You could try `tabular`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{extarticle}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Some very long equations which will be indented slightly.\\
\indent
\begin{tabular}{r@{}p{0.8\linewidth}}
$ A = {} $ & Some very long line which is mostly text but can still include some maths like $ e = mc^2 $ if you so wished\ldots \\
$ \alpha_s = {} $ & A shorter line 
\end{tabular}\\
and then some more normal text\ldots
\end{document}
```

## But `align` is probably a bit better

You will have to decide on the optimal width of the minipage so you can decide how wide you want the section to be:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Now the paragraph spacing is more akin to that in normal maths environments
\begin{align}
A & = \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
Some very long line which is mostly text but can still include some maths like $ e = mc^2 $ if you so wished\ldots 
\end{minipage} \\
\alpha_s & = \text{Something else.}
\end{align}
and we can continue writing without a need for a noindent. 
\end{document}
```